# wp_query if have posts show date but not in loop

Tags: posts, wp-query, date

I have a wp_query set up to show events and I want to show the date if we have posts and if we do not I do not want to show the date.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php

            $today = getdate();
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'category__not_in' => '-9', // When live, will need to add this parameter to all of the loop in this feedLoop.php - Do not forget to include this parameter as this function is needed!!! Cat No will change when live site is up and running!!! 
                 'order' => 'ASC',
                'post_status' => array(
                    'publish',
                    'future',
                ),
                'date_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'year'  => $today['year'],
                        'month' => $today['mon'],
                        'day'   => $today['mday'],
                    ),
                ),
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );



    ?>


<h3><? echo date('l, F jS'); ?></h3> <!-- this is the date
 but I do not want it to echo out three time if 
there are three posts!! -->




<?php if ( have_posts() ) :?> 



        <? while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :?>



        <? $the_query->the_post(); ?>



    <strong><em><?php the_time(); ?></em></strong> - <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="strong"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>There are no posts or pages here</p>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

How can I query the arguments to see if there are posts and if so echoing out the date and hiding if not.  Please someone put me out of my misery as I can not figure this out but it should be easy right?!!

Thanks for any help that I gain in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :?> 

   <?php echo '<h3>' . date('l, F jS') . '</h3>'; ?>

   <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
     // etc.
```

Comment: Tried that and 1, it doesn't hide it when there are no posts and 2, it echos out with the loop but I only want it to display once! Thanks :)

Comment: i think the above code doesn't echo out date multiple times as it is not in the loop and only outputs when there are posts.

Comment: Apologies bravokey, I didn't use the h3 tag that you offered by my own but what you have done is made me realise that I needed to put $thequery in front of have posts - that is where I have gone wrong. Thank you for your assistance it has helped me greatly. I will mark your answer as the correct one. Cheers can happy Sunday :)